# Swift callback in dataTaskWithRequest

Tags: swift2

New to Swift and trying to write a login screen for my app.

My controller:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let emailAddress = emailTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text

    let api = Api()
    api.authenticate(emailAddress!, password: password!)
}
```

Api class:

```
class Api {

    func authenticate(username: String, password: String) -> Bool {   
        var params = [String: String]()
        params["username"] = username
        params["password"] = password
        params["grant_type"] = "password"

        var headers = [String: String]()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        post("authenticate", params: params, headers: headers) {data, response in
            // do something
        }
    }

    func post(location: String, params: [String: String], headers: [String: String], callback: ((data: NSString!, response: NSHTTPURLResponse) -> Void)) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.URL = NSURL(string: Configuration.apiBaseUrl + location)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = NSString(string: getPostBody(params)).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.addValue("Basic " + Configuration.apiAuthorization, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let data = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            callback(data: data, response: httpResponse)
            return
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

As I plan to add more API methods after authentication, I want generic POST/PUT/GET/DELETE methods. I am trying to understand how I can best set up the callbacks in Swift so the post call in the authenticate method can return true/false and show like a dialog on the UI thread. Returning a boolean in the post call in the authenticate method is not allowed now, because it expects Void.

I am familiar with callbacks in nodejs and trying to grasp this now. Any hints what the best approach would be?

Comment: any solutions so far?